# how can i install the CDT plugins in eclipse windows7

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm working in eclipse, which has Java, PHP, ant, XML

Now I need to work with C++(cygwin/CDT). So how can I add it to eclipse?

I downloaded "eclipse-SDK-4.2-win32" and installed it, but it doesn't show php plugins, though I need to work with PHP and C++.

I searched on the net to install the CDT, and its installed, I think but its not showing CDT plugins.

I've been trying to install the plugin for three days, I believe it's installed but not showing plugin CDT.

My task is Cygwin based, I need to get this to work this because I am very new to this job.

Answer (score 0):

This might help, regarding the CDT part:
http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html

Once installed, CDT provides a specific perspective you can use to write, compile and execute C and C++ programs.

Note it's not enough to just install this Eclipse plugin: a C/C++ compiler must also be installed separately, as described in the above link.

for PHP, you need another plugin, called PDT :
http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.pdt